# Add a gradient of intensiy to an interference plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot the gradient plot of intensities, something like this:

[image: plot]

I though myself about creating a gradient grid whose distribution was my **"I" function**, but I have no idea how to do it or if there is an explicit package in R to accomplish this task.

Thank you so much for even thinking about this.

```
a <- 5*10^(-6)
d <- 0.5*0.005
l <- 500*10^(-9)
n <- pi
theta <- seq(-n,n,length=3500)

I <- function(x){(cos((pi*d*sin(x))/l))^2*(sin((pi*a*sin(x))/l)/((pi*a*sin(x))/l))^2} 
y1 <- lapply(theta,I)
y <- unlist(y1)
df <- data.frame(theta,y)

I2 <- function(x){(sin((pi*a*sin(x))/l)/((pi*a*sin(x))/l))^2} 
y12 <- lapply(theta,I2)
y2 <- unlist(y12)
df2 <- data.frame(theta,y2)

p = ggplot()

p + 
  geom_line(data = df, aes(theta,y)) + 
  xlim(-0.3,0.3) + 
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(theta,y2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of `patchwork` this could be achieved like so:

1. For the gradient make a second ggplot of rectangles using e.g. `geom_rect` where you map intensity on `color` and/or `fill`
2. This gradient plot could then be glued to the main plot via `patchwork`

To get a nice gradient plot

1. I tripled the number of grid points for the gradient plot,
2. mapped the *cubic root* of intensity on `color` and
3. get rid of all unnecessary elemnts like y-axis, color guide, ...

BTW:

1. As your functions are  vectorized you don't need `lapply` to compute the intensities.
2. Instead of adjusting the limits via `xlim()` (which removes rows falling outside of the range), set them using `coord_cartesian`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(patchwork)

a <- 5*10^(-6)
d <- 0.5*0.005
l <- 500*10^(-9)
n <- pi
theta <- seq(-n,n,length=3500)

I <- function(x){(cos((pi*d*sin(x))/l))^2*(sin((pi*a*sin(x))/l)/((pi*a*sin(x))/l))^2} 
y <- I(theta)
df <- data.frame(theta,y)

I2 <- function(x){(sin((pi*a*sin(x))/l)/((pi*a*sin(x))/l))^2}
y2 <- I2(theta)
df2 <- data.frame(theta,y2)

p1 = ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = df, aes(theta,y)) + 
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(theta,y2)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-0.3,0.3))

g <- tibble(
  xmin = seq(-n, n, length = 3 * 3500),
  xmax = dplyr::lead(xmin),
  y = I(xmin)
)

p2 <- ggplot(g, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = 0, ymax = 1, color = y^(1/3))) +
  geom_rect() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-0.3,0.3)) +
  guides(color = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank())

p1 / p2 + plot_layout(heights = c(10, 1))
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_rect).
```

[image]